# Can I run multiple cores at different clock speeds?

Tags: linux, cpu, x86, cpu-frequency

I see the cores on an Intel i5 machine I'm looking at can only be run at the same clockspeed: `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/related_cpus` lists all of the CPUs. Setting cpu1's clockspeed changes cpu0's, as expected.

Supposedly the AMD A6-4400M machine I'm running should be able to run each core at a different clockspeed:`/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/related_cpu` only lists cpu1. When I set cpu1's clockspeed by using the performance governor and echoing 1400000 to `scaling_max_freq`, cpu0's clockspeed remains at 2700000 as expected. Cpu1's scaling_cur_freq reads 1400000 as expected.

However, cpu1's `cpuinfo_cur_freq` reads 2700000. From benchmarking, it appears CPU1 is indeed still running at 2.7 GHz. Am I missing something, or is something broken?

I'm running Linux 2.6.35, and passing `idle=mwait` in the kernel command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This is not yet close to be a definite answer. Instead, it's a set of suggestions too long to fit in comments.*

I'm afraid you might slightly misinterpret the meanings of sysfs cpufreq parameters. For instance, on my *Core Duo* laptop, the `related_cpu` parameters for both cores read `0 1` - which, according to your interpretation, would mean that the cores cannot switch frequencies independently. But that is not the case - I can set each frequency at will. By contrast, the **`affected_cpus`** parameter for each core lists only the respective CPU number.

You might want to take a look at kernel documentation for cpu-freq to get a better understanding of the parameters such as `affected_cpus`,`related_cpus`,`scaling_*` and `cpuinfo_*`. The documentation is normally distributed with kernel source packages. Specifically, I recommend reading **`<kernel-sources-dir>/Documentation/cpu-freq/user-guide.txt`**, where `<kernel-sources-dir>` would typically stand for `/usr/src/linux` or `/usr/src/linux-<kernel-version>`. (However, when I skim through the documentation myself now, I confess I don't catch some of the frequency-scaling-related nuances. To fully understand these, one probably needs to gain a solid understanding of CPU architectures first.)

Back to your question. And one more test case on my part: when I change the value of `scaling_max_freq` (with either `userspace` or `performance` governor being used), the core's clock automatically switches to that new maximum. The different behaviour you're observing might be any of:

- specific to hardware implementation of frequency scaling mechanisms on your CPU,
- due to differences between the standard `cpufreq` module and `phc-intel` which I'm using,
- normal behaviour (call it a bug or a feature if you will) of `cpufreq` module, which has changed at some point since `2.6.35` (my current kernel version is `3.6.2`),
- result of a bug in `cpufreq` implementation for your CPU (or entire family),
- specific to the implementation of `performance` CPU governor as of `2.6.35`.

Some of the things you might do to push your investigation further:

- read the `user-guide.txt` and fiddle more with other `cpufreq` parameters,
- repeat the tests while running a newer kernel - the easiest way is to boot a liveCD/DVD/USB.

If you continue to experience unexpected behaviour and gain more reasons to believe it is due to a bug (definitely must check with the latest minor kernel version), go ahead and report this on [kernel.org bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/).